# LinearRegionItem in Pyqtgraph

Tags: pyqtgraph

I have 4 PlotWidgets (using pyqtgraph as pg) created as:

```
for i in range(4):
    myPlot[i] = pg.PlotWidget(myWindow);
```

In each PlotWidget, I want to divide the x-axis to several regions with equal width (RegionWidth). Therfore, I have M = x-axis Range/RegionWidth. So I initialize region selection lines as:

```
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(M):
        ROI[i][j] = pg.LinearRegionItem()
        ROI[i][j].setZValue(-10)
        myPlot[i].addItem(ROI[i][j])
        ROI[i][j].setRegion([xmin + j*RegionWidth, xmin +((j+1)*RegionWidth)-1])
```

The problem:
When I want to remove and clear these regions, I can't! I tried:

```
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(M):
        myPlot[i].removeItem(ROI[i][j])
```

It only clears the regions in the fourth PlotWidget. I want to remove/clear the four plots from these regions without affecting other items in the PlotWidget.

Comment: The code you posted works as expected for me. Please post a complete code example.

Comment: It does. It was an error of bad indenting.
It took me 3 days to realize it.
Thanks

Comment: In that case, consider closing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works good. It was an error of bad indenting.